# HDFS API - count the number of directories, files and bytes

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

How do you get the DIR_COUNT, FILE_COUNT, CONTENT_SIZE FILE_NAME in HDFS programatically in Scala/Java? (Not through Shell)

```
val fileStatus = fileSystem.getFileStatus(new Path(path))
val fileByteSize = fileStatus.getLen
```

FileSystem API doesn't seem to have those information. I can only get the file size of 1 file (code above). But I don't get the file count and byte size per directory.

I'm looking for a similar behavior to:

```
hdfs dfs -count [-q] <paths>
```

which count the number of directories, files and bytes under the path provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FileSystem.listStatus](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) method to get information about files and directories in a given HDFS directory.

You can use the returned array of `FileStatus` objects to calculate total size, count of files, etc.

Comment: How to use  FileSystem.listStatus to get size of all subdirectories ? It seems that getLen() of sub dir returns 0 bytes